# Latex \cite shows question marks instead of numbers

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I know that this question has been asked before, but in different contexts, and the answers have not been helpful for me.  Following are a very simple .tex file and .bib file.  The output pdf has a question mark inside the square brackets, rather than a number (which should be 1).  How can I fix this?

article.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\begin{document}
The citation: \cite{test123}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

bibliography.bib

```
@inproceedings(test123,
  title={On the possibility of an event},
  author={Schwartz, Daniel G},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 18th International Conference on Artificial Intelligence (ICAI'16); held as part of WorldComp'16},
  pages={47--51},
  month={July 25--28},
  address={ Las Vegas, NV, USA},
  year={2016},
 }
```

Comment: There are no `\bibliographystyle`.

Comment: In addition to providing a suitable `\bibliographystyle` directive and choosing a suitable citation management package (such as `cite` or `natbib`), you must also run BibTeX between LaTeX runs.

Comment: There's also a mistake (probably caused by a typo...) in your BibTeX file: It should be `@inproceedings{test123,`, not `@inproceedings(test123,`.

Comment: Here are revised versions of my two files, in response to your comments.  I'm still getting the same result.  I am working inside the MikTeX/Texworks system, using the pdfLaTeX environment.  I don't see any way to directly run BibTex.  It seems that this should all work in that system. Any further advice will be appreciated.

Comment: You wrote, "I don't see any way to directly run BibTex." Since you're using TeXworks, look for the window (probably in the upper left) that tells you which program is run when you click on the green compile triangle. In all likelihood, "pdfLaTeX" is the default choice. Click inside that window to make a drop-down menu visible. To run BibTeX, you'd select (what else?) "BibTeX". When you're done, don't forget to revert to "pdfLaTeX"; then, run pdfLaTeX twice to propagate all changes.